# Permanent client/server connection in Symfony

Tags: ajax, symfony, websocket, stream, connection

I'm doing a pet project with Symfony. In it, I scrape and parse the content of a few websites and APIs (it's all for personal use), and mix everything together. Up until now, I've been separating all the different retrieval processes, and basically it works like this: I have a menu, and each button updates something. When I push it, some website is loaded, the content is parsed and my database is updated. This takes some time, depending on the website loading time, the parsing etc. Basically, when I choose to update something, I lose control and I have no output about the situation until everything is done.

I'm rethinking the whole process, and the way I see this is having a page where I push a button, and a "permanent" connection is established with the server. Then, one thing a time, everything is updated. This could take some time (I would guess even 20 minutes), and therefore the server notifies the client with updates, and possibly even requires the user to make choices (I'm connecting data from different sources, and there are a few edge cases where it just can't automatically guess the right relationships).

I'm thinking about the best way to implement this. At first I thought simple Ajax/jQuery would work, but it seems to me that the relationship between client/server is too permanent and bidirectional to be able to keep everything simple. Then I thought about working with streams and/or websockets, but I don't really know the topics.

What is the best/correct way to do this, especially in a Symfony context?

Comment: If automated process would be normal for you, for the temporary solution, I'd create a command (Console Component) to do this job and set a cronjob to execute it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is really tight to Symfony, what you are looking for is called Server Sent Events.

> Server-sent events (SSE) is a technology for a browser to get
>   automatic updates from a server via HTTP connection. The Server-Sent
>   Events EventSource API is standardized as part of HTML5 by the W3C.

For PHP in general, I generally use the [Hoa\EventSource](https://github.com/hoaproject/Eventsource) library which makes things easy

For Symfony, you can have a dedicated API endpoint that will use this library.

Comment: This would work, but I kind of need to sometimes be able to send data back to the server. Maybe I could expose an API and with Ajax I'd connect to that, while the main update process sleeps and every tot seconds it checks if a value has been updated?

Comment: Yep then websockets are maybe more useful as they provide full-duplex communications